# Strange internet timeout issue

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, routing, internet, timeout

Working with a client, setup a new server for them 3 weeks ago. The It's a Windows 2016 server, replacing an SBS server; the domain is already setup, I had initially started to setup RDS, but removed that and just installed the Essentials Role for remote web access instead. Everything has been fine so far. I send an email to the ISP today to update port forwards to the new server in the Mikrotik router (they say this is already done, but the RWA link still points to the old server) I get a call from the client 2 hours later saying internet is down and Outlook won't connect (O365).

So I am able to teamviewer in...and all the machines say they have internet access and pinging IPs and domain names works fine, nslookup brings back results as expected but websites timeout (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT), Outlook won't connect out, etc.

I call a guy from the ISP and he gets in and reboots the wireless antenna and the mikrotik router. I get booted of course, but teamviewer connects back up, I type in a search and it actually goes and google brings up a result, but then goes right back to not working, same as before.

I have google DNS forwarders on the server/domain controller, DHCP machines get DNS from the ISP router (their DNS). Either way nothing is going out. I didn't change anything today and they say they didn't change anything today.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: This is a Windows AD domain. The Domain Controller should be providing DNS to the domain clients, not the router. The clients should be configured to use the DC as their one and only DNS server (based on the scenario that they have only one DC/DNS server). The Domain Controller can use any forwarders you like or it can use the root hint servers only... it's your choice. So... get the DC and domain clients configured correctly as far as DNS is concerned and then see if that resolves the issues.

Comment: Most workstations are configured with the DC as the primary DNS, which has Google DNS forwarders set; The ones that have pull DNS from DHCP I just switched to test if that changed anything, and it did not help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Server Fault! Did your ISP forward `port 53`, too?

Comment: Hi, I don't know for sure but I don't think so.